# Alert user on database change

Tags: php, database

I have a bugtracker and eveytime a new bug is added to the database the other users online have to refresh the page to know about it.

Is it possible to alert the users about a new bug added?

I'm using PHP and MySQL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean alerting without page refresh? AJAX could get this done for you, these steps should be taken:

```
1) Create a php script that fetches the new bugs
2) Add a javascript function that gets the data off the PHP file using getAJAX/getJSON
3) If there is any new data: create an alert or perhaps make a nice looking CSS popup in one corner (or middle) of the screen
```

Be aware that:

```
1) You should send some kind of unique identification of a user along with the request to the PHP file, this way you can 'track' which user should have been notified about a bug already.
2) You choose a good interval (e.g. would u use 5 seconds, 2 seconds, 1 seconde, even less?)
```

Comment: Sending an AJAX request every second is _insane_.

Comment: As I said, he has to choose a good interval himself. It's worthless having a 10 second interval if there is a page where a user hardly stays on for a couple of seconds. If the page he is talking about is just 1 page without any subpages, then a 30 second interval would be ok aswel..

Answer (score 0):

You can send an AJAX request to the server every minute asking for changed.

Comment: Ho do I send that request? I know how to create the ajax function for that, what I don't know is how to send the Ajax every minute, for instance

Comment: Use the `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a meta refresh in the page to keep it reloading every few minutes.

Alternatively you could write some gnarly javascript/ajax and alert the user in a modal window/alert box that the current page has changed.

I'm guessing that you don't mean you want to email the other users to notify them?

Comment: I can't reaload the page because the user my be writing a new case and then it will be reloaded =( and sending a email is a option but the user will need to check the e-mail everytime....

Comment: Ok - go with my second suggestion then. Ajax polled every minute or so and a modal window or alert box.